# Convert Javascript regex to PHP regex?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, preg-match

I'm using the following regex from emailregex.com to validate emails on my site. It's working like a charm in JS but I'm unable to get it working within PHP.

> /^(([^<>()[]\.,;:\s@"]+(.[^<>()[]\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

The issue from what I'm seeing is the backslashes, when adding it in quotes it keeps trying to escape it. Regex101 shows that it is working, it's just a matter of how to get it into PHP.

Any help would be great, thanks!

PHP Code:

```
$emailRegex = "/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/"
```

Comment: Post code from php script which not working

Comment: @diavolic See post, that var would be used in a `preg_match()` but the issue isn't with the match, it's that the string is trying to be escaped and I don't know how to make it so it's not being escaped.

Comment: If you cannot convert it at once - do it step by step, converting isolated parts one after another.

Comment: Test your regex in https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes `'` around regex text instead of double quotes `"`

```
  $emailRegex = '/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/';
```

Because you have used `"` in your regex,

Otherwise you need to escape `"` also by `\"`

Live demo : https://eval.in/763141

Comment: `Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '^' `

Comment: Please provide any live demo like in eval.in

Comment: @Niklesh Thank you, it seems that coding for 3 days straight hasn't been very good on me. I missed that within my code I was trying to append onto the start and end of that regex `/` which was causing the error. Regardless you helped me out so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regular exprssion.

Use PHP's **filter_var** functions:

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "This ($email) email address is considered valid.\n";
}
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php

You may choose to use a type="email" input on the client side.  Disabling validation with the **novalidate** attribute on the form prevents the browser from changing the appearance of inputs based on the validity of their contents, but still allows you to use JavaScript to test.

```js
var statusDiv = document.getElementById("status");
document.getElementById("email").addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
  statusDiv.textContent = this.checkValidity() ? "Valid" : "Not valid";
});
```

```html
<form novalidate>
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" autocomplete="email" id="email">
</form>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: Thought about this option and had it working but I want my backend validation to match my front-end validation. The regex works and doesn't seem to be showing any issues.

Comment: @JoeScotto - Are you using an input with a type="email" on the client side?

Comment: No, I want to control my validation from JS to keep it inline with my php validation. The messages from the email type mess with the whole design of my site also